# How to test Microservice on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, microservices

There is a project migrated from legacy to GCP.
On GCP everything runs on microservices.
May be around 40-50 microservice.
I would like to automate this microservices but there is no endpoint exposed in this project.
How could you automate a microservice where there are no endpoints?
What type of architecture, you could use to test this?
Db: Firestore (nosql)

Thanks
M

Comment: Can you elaborate on "no endpoints exposed in this project"?   Isn't it the case that a micro service must have some mechanism for it to be called ... wouldn't that exposed interface be an endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

In my view you can do it following way:

1. Use ClusterIP or NodePort to access those POD.
2. Spin up a new POD which will access your target POD to communicate.
3. You can enable POD to POD communication based on labels and enabling network policy.
4. You can use calico as network policy agent.
5. You can view the log of your testing pod using kubectl logs [pod name] or from logging service of your cloud provider or even using daemonset that you could install.
6. The testing POD can periodically send traffic. So you can use thread to call the target service and keep the thread in sleep mode for a while or you can use kubernetes cronjob to call the target service. Based on your usecase it will be chosen.

Let me know if it meets your requirements or you have more to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of finding out how to test your micro-services on the Google Cloud Platform, I would suggest referencing our documentation on "[Microservices Architecture on Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine)" as it will explain and guild you how to implement your services onto GCP. You may also look into this [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/designing-microservice-api) as well as it provides the best practices for designing APIs to communicate between microservices.

Additionally, user "[ARINDAM BANERJEE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11042217/arindam-banerjee)" has a great example you can follow as well.